# Can the home partition be created as an extended partition?

Tags: partitioning

Hi guys I"m a rookie to the Ubuntu OS.Can I have my home partition as an extended drive? Eager to hear the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - how exactly do you mean though? I'm sort of assuming you mean 'extended partition', in which case it's no different to any other partition in this context - although if you mean 'a separate physical drive' or 'in another room' then it's still yes :).

The normal setup is that you can have 4 primary partitions, and any more have to use one of the 4 as a 'frame' to fit within that limit, hence are termed 'extended partitions'. You can have loads if you really want!